# unable to update react app's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a React course and trying to update the state (profiles) in the App.

When I clicked at the button, I could see the new profile for a few milliseconds and then it would return to a list of the original two profiles.

Which part did I get it wrong? Thanks.

Here is the App showing some profiles and a button to add a new one.

```
// app.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Profile from './Profile';
import AddProfile from './AddProfile';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profiles: [
        {name: 'Joan', age: 30, bio: 'enjoys swimming and biking', hobbies: ['swimming', 'biking']},
        {name: 'John', age: 40, bio: 'enjoys long walks on the beach', hobbies: ['gardening', 'TV']}
      ]
    };
  }


  addUser = (newProfile) => {
    this.setState({
      profiles: this.state.profiles.concat([newProfile])
    })
  };

  render() {
    let profiles = this.state.profiles.map(profile => {
      return (
        <Profile
          name={profile.name}
          age={profile.age}
          bio={profile.bio}
          hobbies={profile.hobbies}
        />
      )
    });

    return <div className="App">
      {profiles}
      <AddProfile addUser={this.addUser}/>
    </div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Another class to deal with Adding profiles. A lot of repetitions but most doing the same thing again and again for four attributes in each profile.

```
// AddProfile.js

import React from "react";

class AddProfile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'your name', // default
      age: '',
      bio: '',
      hobbies: ''
    }
  }

  handleName = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  };

  handleAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      age: e.target.value
    })
  };

  handleBio = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      bio: e.target.value
    })
  };

  handleHobbies = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      hobbies: [e.target.value]
    })
  };

  handleClick = (e) => {
    let newProfile = {
      name: this.state.name,
      age: this.state.age,
      bio: this.state.bio,
      hobbies: [this.state.hobbies]
    };
    this.props.addUser(newProfile);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <p>Add a new profile</p>
          <input onChange={this.handleName} id="name" value={this.state.name} />
          <br/>
          <input onChange={this.handleAge} id="age" value={this.state.age} />
          <br/>
          <input onChange={this.handleBio} id="bio" value={this.state.bio} />
          <br/>
          <input onChange={this.handleHobbies} id="hobbies" value={this.state.hobbies} />
          <br/>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add New Profile</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AddProfile;
```

An isolated function for the Profile rendering component.

```
// Profile.js

import React from 'react';

let Profile = props => (
  <div>
    <h3>{props.name}</h3>
    <p>
      {props.name} is {props.age} and {props.bio}
    </p>
    <h4>Hobbies:</h4>
    <ul>
      {props.hobbies.map(hobby=><li>{hobby}</li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

export default Profile;
```

Scratching my head for a while now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you don't prevent the default browser behavior of your `form`, which is to reload the browser.

Use `preventDefault` on the event given to `handleClick` and it will work as expected.

```
handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let newProfile = {
    name: this.state.name,
    age: this.state.age,
    bio: this.state.bio,
    hobbies: [this.state.hobbies]
  };

  this.props.addUser(newProfile);
};
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() fixes my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because your not adding a key on your Profile Component : [React Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Try with this :

```
  render() {
  let profiles = this.state.profiles.map((profile, index) => {
  return (
    <Profile
      key={index}
      name={profile.name}
      age={profile.age}
      bio={profile.bio}
      hobbies={profile.hobbies}
    />
  )
});

return <div className="App">
  {profiles}
  <AddProfile addUser={this.addUser}/>
</div>;
  }
}
```

PS : You don't need to have the 'key' in the props of your Profile Component, it's only used by React.

Answer (score -1):

first, **dont mutate state values**, so replace your function:

```
addUser = (newProfile) => {
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      profiles: [...prevState.profiles, newProfile ]
    }))
  };
```

`Array.prototype.concat()` mutating the array.
about `setState`:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: Concat does not mutate the state [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat)